# Convert grayscale image to it's negative using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to make a simple function to convert a grayscale image to it's negative using **openCV**. Below I have the function's code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "common.h"
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
.........................................

void negative_image()
{
    Mat img = imread("Images/cameraman.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    for (int i = 0; i < img.row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++)
        {
            img.at<uchar>(i, j) = 255 - img.at<uchar>(i, j);
        }
    }

    imshow("negative image", img);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

When I try to build the application I get the following errors:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `i < img.rows` maybe instead if `row`?

Comment: Yeah, that was it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why the loop, when you can subtract a scalar in a single (optimized) [matrix expression](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions)? `img = 255 - img;`.

Comment: @DanMašek put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i < img.rows` instead of `row`.

Answer (score 7):

OpenCV provides a wide variety of matrix operations that can be combined in [matrix expressions](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions). Subtraction of a matrix from a scalar is one of those.

Hence, a simple function to convert a grayscale image to its negative would in my eyes look something like this:

```
cv::Mat invert_image(cv::Mat const& input)
{
    return 255 - input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all your code is correct but its **img.rows** not row  so the correct one is

> for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)

Comment: That code is unnecessarily complex and suboptimal on top. See my comment to the question. If in OpenCV you need to manually iterate over the pixels, it's usually a hint to stop, think (and consult the documentation). Often there's a terser and more efficient tool provided to achieve the same.